# Splitting a String /StringBuilder using page break

Tags: java, regex, apache-poi

I have a String and a StringBuilder containing a word document content which was returned by Apache poi api exactly the `org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument` class , I want to split it based on page break, because i want to parse the word document pages , edit every page and save it into a new word document.

Is there a way to do it with regular expression or another solution?

Comment: Do you mean proper Word page breaks (which force a new page) or do you just want to know when the text has naturally flowed onto the next page?

Comment: i want to retrieve every word page content in seperate String Object.

Comment: I hope you did find a solution because as far as I know it is not possible using Apache POI